# JSP - update current page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page where i can open some code. I implemented a function which analyzes the open code.

My current situation:

In my `index.jsp` I have this `codeEditor` and a `button`

```
<form action="AnalysisServlet" method="post" target="_blank">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="codeEditor" style="margin-top: 15px;">Code:</label>
        <textarea name="codeEditor" class="form-control" id="codeEditor" rows="15" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="analysisButton">
        <button type="submit" id="startAnalysis" class="btn btn-default btn-block" style="margin-top: 10px;">Start analysis</button>        
    </div>
</form>
```

My servlet just have a `doPost` Method

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 
    // create bean
    MainVisitor mainVisitor = new MainVisitor();
    request.setAttribute("mainVisitor", mainVisitor);

    // get SQL from index.jsp
    mainVisitor.setSql(request.getParameter("codeEditor"));

    request.getSession().setAttribute("analysisAttr", mainVisitor);
    request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/analysis.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

the result of my analysis will shown in a new jsp

```
<textarea name="codeEditor" class="form-control" id="codeEditor" rows="15" style="resize: none;">${sessionScope.analysisAttr.result}</textarea>
```

My Problem: I need to stay in the `index.jsp` and update/expand a `textarea`

Is this possible without ajax? I really know nothing about ajax so it would be brilliant if I can stay in my jsp, servelt, java contex :/

thanks :)

Comment: long time since I worked with servlets and JSP, but did you try `include` instead of `forward`?

Comment: i tried now, in my browser it opens a new tab with the text in the comment. it's like `forward`

Comment: The only way doing it without AJAX is to make the user "think" he stayed on the same page by forwarding to index.jsp, make index.jsp redisplay the same input, and the additional result.

Comment: hmm okay then I will try AJAX. I think the other solutions are dirty solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

I removed the form and added this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#analysisButton', function(){
    $.get("AnalysisServlet",function(responseText){
        $("#commentBox").text(responseText);
    });
});
```